# Identificar status de um programa com java

Tags: java

Existe alguma maneira de identificar o status de um programa no Windows pesquisando pelo processo abertos com o java?

Estou a procura de uma forma de mapear um processo específico de um executável para saber se o mesmo está em foco na tela ou minimizado, assim parando o processo de um macro, pausando a execução da classe Robot quando minimizado o executável tipo a calculadora do windows por exemplo.

Answer (score 2):

Você pode tentar isso:

```
try {
    String line;
    Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec
          (System.getenv("windir") +"\\system32\\"+"calc.exe");
    BufferedReader input =
            new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
    while ((line = input.readLine()) != null) {
        System.out.println(line); //<-- Parse data here.
    }
    input.close();
} catch (Exception err) {
    err.printStackTrace();
}
```

Outras possibilidades:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54686/how-to-get-a-list-of-current-open-windows-process-with-java